# Exist an event in Javascript when the user stop select the text of a input or textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events, textarea

I have this code in Javascript:

```
var lastTextSelected = "";
//BOTH ELEMENTS ARE TEXTAREA
jQuery('#ingredients').select(selectedText);
jQuery('#steps').select(selectedText);
```

and this is the `selectedText` function:

```
function selectedText() {
        lastTextSelected = window.getSelection().toString();
}
```

My current objective is when the user stops selecting the current selected text of the elements, empty the content of the variable named `lastTextSelected = "";`

Is there an event in jQuery or Javascript for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the onselect event like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
    console.log('event fired')
}
```

```css
textarea{
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area" onselect="myFunction()">select me</textarea>
```

Every time now text is selected myFunction is fired.

Comment: The problem is when the user stops selecting the text, when the user selects the text I doesn´t have any problem, but thankx for your time.

Comment: This does exactly what you are asking for right. When the user stops selecting the text the event is fired. Take a look again.